# .NET 6 API populate extended ProblemDetails class with the default response values

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I want to return all error responses in my API in the application/problem+json format. By default, returning an empty `NotFound()` or `BadRequest()` already results in this format. When they are passed values however (e.g. `BadRequest("blah")`), they lose this format.

Is there any way to return a `ProblemDetails` object with additional properties, without having to populate the default `ProblemDetails` properties by hand? I want to avoid using exception handlers for this, since I don't want to throw exceptions only for the sake of response formatting.

Response should look something like this:

```json
{
  // should be auto-populated with values that an empty NotFound() generates
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
  "title": "Not Found",
  "status": 404,
  "traceId": "00-7d554354b54a8e6be652c2ea65434e55-a453edeb85b9eb80-00",
  // what i want to add
  "additionalProperties": {
    "example": "blah"
  }
}
```

Comment: A Request/Response has three parts 1) The URL 2) HTTP Headers 3) Body.  What you are showing in the response are HTTP headers.  There are standard Headers and Custom Headers.  A header has a Key like "status" and a "value".  If you want a complex header (additional properties) it must be in the body and not the header.  Or you can make the value a CSV string to contain more than one item.

Comment: @jdweng the question shows a response body, formatted as the Problem Details standard: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807

Comment: @JoshNoe : Look carefully you link.   The content is the body.  Everything else are HTTP headers.  The link is a RFC specification that contains lots of options.  The OP wants the data as HTTP headers, not JSON body.  The curly brackets in OP expected results make code look like JSON, but it is really HTTP headers.  Status is a header.  Not part of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, going off of Giacomo De Liberali answer, I did some digging and found a decent solution.

I looked up the source code for the default implementation of [ProblemDetailsFactory](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v6.0.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultProblemDetailsFactory.cs) (v6.0.1) and wrote a service that works similarly. This way I can avoid throwing exceptions when I'm returning an fully expected error response.

I used the `IHttpAccessor` service instead of passing the HttpContext as parameter. This service needs to be registered beforehand like this in `Problem.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

I populate the default fields for the `ProblemDetails` instance with the help of the `IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions>` service that's registered by default.

Finally, I pass an optional object as parameter in the `Create(..)` method and add it's properties with the `problemDetails.Extensions.Add(...)` method.

Here's the full implementation I'm using currently:

```cs
public class ProblemService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
        private readonly ApiBehaviorOptions _options;

        public ProblemService(IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _options = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
        }

        public ProblemDetails Create(int? statusCode = null, object? extensions = null)
        {
            var context = _contextAccessor.HttpContext ?? throw new NullReferenceException();

            statusCode ??= 500;

            var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
            {
                Status = statusCode,
                Instance = context.Request.Path
            };

            if (extensions != null)
            {
                foreach (var extension in extensions.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
                {
                    problemDetails.Extensions.Add(extension.Name, extension.GetValue(extensions, null));
                }
            }

            ApplyProblemDetailsDefaults(context, problemDetails, statusCode.Value);

            return problemDetails;
        }

        private void ApplyProblemDetailsDefaults(HttpContext httpContext, ProblemDetails problemDetails, int statusCode)
        {
            problemDetails.Status ??= statusCode;

            if (_options.ClientErrorMapping.TryGetValue(statusCode, out var clientErrorData))
            {
                problemDetails.Title ??= clientErrorData.Title;
                problemDetails.Type ??= clientErrorData.Link;
            }

            var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? httpContext?.TraceIdentifier;
            if (traceId != null)
            {
                problemDetails.Extensions["traceId"] = traceId;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's how to use it after injecting it into the controller:

```cs
return Unauthorized(_problem.Create(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, new
{
    I18nKey = LoginFailureTranslationKey.AccessFailed
));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [ProblemDetailsFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.problemdetailsfactory?view=aspnetcore-6.0) resolving it from DI to create an instance of a `ProblemDetails`. One of the parameters is the status code, and you can return from your action `Problem(_factory.CreateProbelmDetails(…))`